# How to change color of the equation numbers?

Tags: equations, color, number

I would like to put part of text in different colors. I have a problem with equations as the equation numbers remain in black. See e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

This text is written in black and the equations too:
\begin{equation}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
  \textrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
\end{eqnarray}

\color{red}
Now we write in red, but the equation numbers are still in black!
\begin{equation}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \textrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to load the package `amsmath`.

Answer (score 2):

As @campa has already pointed out in a comment, your formatting objective is achieved automatically if the `amsmath` package is loaded.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
This text is written in black and the equations too:
\begin{gather}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1 \\
  \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
\end{gather}

\color{red}
Now we write in red, and the equation numbers are also in red.
\begin{gather}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1 \\
  \mathrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `amsmath`. We have to delete `\normalcolor` inside the definition of `\@eqnnum`. I have added `\color{red}` instead of that, but you also can omit it, to make the equation number affected by `\color` changes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \color{red} (\theequation)}}% \normalcolor deleted, \color{...} added
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \textrm{e}^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely ii is preferible to use \mathrm instead of \textrm in mathmode. +1

Comment: Your setup changes the color of equation numbers to red *globally*, which doesn't seem to be what the OP is looking to achieve. Can you add a couple of sentences to mention how the color switch could be localized?

Comment: @Mico I have mentioned that. Simply omit `\color{...}` inside the definition. Then the equation number will be influenced by `\color` changes.

Comment: @WeißerKater - Instead of redefining `\@eqnnum`, it might be easier -- certainly easier to remember -- to issue the directives `\renewcommand\normalcolor{\color{red}}` and `\renewcommand\normalcolor{\color{black}}`before and after the red-colored zones.

Answer (score 0):

Redifinition tagform@

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\color{red}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```